# I want to make a procedure that has column and table as variables

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I'm painfully new to SQL/mySQL as a whole so I'm flying blind right now so apologies.

I made a procedure in mySQL that selects a varchar data from a specific column and table, turn it into INT (contents of said column are numerical to begin with) and output its values after going through a mathematical operation as a (very simple) attempt in data masking. As follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE qdwh.mask_varchar_num2(tablename varchar(100), colname varchar (100))
BEGIN
set @a=concat('select','(','(','(','(','select',colname ,'from',tablename,')','+','0',')','+','297',')','*','5',')','as','colname');
prepare query from @a;
execute query;
deallocate prepare query;
END
```

but when i tried to call the procedure with the following line:

```
select [column] , mask_varchar_num2 ([column]) from [table];
```

an error "FUNCTION qdwh.mask_varchar_num2 does not exist" shows up. I wanted the script to output a select function of the column in question after the conversion to INT and the mathematical operation done to it, so i can then use this procedure in a larger script ("create table select as" kinda stuff) to convert the whole table into masked data as needed.

Is there something i am missing and what am i doing wrong? Dbeaver acknowledges the procedure script as legit so i dont know whats wrong. Thanks in advance for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Procedures are run by using `call` and cannot be called within a select query.  To define a function, you need to use `create function`.

Comment: Agreed. And a function does not allow DDL. Besides, it has to return a value.

Comment: ive tried that too actually. a call mask_varchar_num2 ([table], [column]), it also returns an error of "unknown column [name of the table] in 'field list'"

Comment: I would suggest adding a `select @a ;` statement in the procedure to find out what the literal value of the query to be made. It's not uncommon that a complicated concat actually returns something unintended.

Comment: @dru.d 1) you seem to be passing the name of the column as object identifier as not as a string literal to your stored program and you seem to be passing only 1 parameter, while your stored proc expects two. 2) The bigger problem is that I do not understand why you made this stored procedure / function in the first place! A simple cast would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer but here's what your select looks like..

```
set @colname='a';
set @tablename='t';

set @a=concat('select','(','(','(','(','select',@colname ,'from',@tablename,')','+','0',')','+','297',')','*','5',')','as','colname');

select @a


'select((((selectafromt)+0)+297)*5)ascolname'
```

missing a lot of spaces between tokens